# Set Object's "Viewport Display" according to Workspace

Tags: 3d-view, interface, workflow, workspaces

I do a lot of retopology and I want to make a new Workspace exclusively to it. So it should have **Backface Culling** (Viewport Shading) and **In Front** (Object Viewport Display) options turned on.

I can set the **Backface Culling** to work dependent on the workspace, but the Object Viewport Display is not changing. Can I make it work?

[image]

Comment: Because the setting is for the selected object and not the scene (or workspace). You can set *In Front* for one object and it won't affect any other object.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't affect other objects, that's not the problem.
What I want is to set the **In Front** to the active object, just like changing to _UV Editing_ changes the active object to _Edit Mode_.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue and I accidentally solved it by going to solid viewport shading instead of material viewport shading in the top right of the viewport. Hopefully this helps anybody else looking for an answer.